# Symfony sylius installation cache rename

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to run the command : app/console sylius:install
But at some point it always stop with this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException' with message
>   'Cannot rename %DEV_TEMP_%'

I know it's a problem of two process trying to access one file or maybe files right but i dont know right to do for this ?

Any ideas ?

I'm running the lastest Wamp apache 2.4 php 5.5 Mysql 5.6

Comment: Interesting... do you have a stack trace for this error message? You can get it by running `app/console sylius:install --verbose`.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was discussed here: 
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/2604

There shouldn't exists permissions problems on Win platform so it could be a persistent sylius problem repeated in some versions.

New version 0.16 dev. is fixed.

For avoiding problems try to clear composer cache first, delete old Sylius files (backup them) and regenerate Database.